# How to maintain the aspect ratio of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am creating an application that I believe would be better if it could maintain its aspect ratio when expanding\minimizing. I set the minimum size to be 1000x800 and would like it to maintain this ratio of 5:4.

Is there a method for that already or will I need to add an event handler myself that checks if the frame has been resized it will give it the closest size possible?

PS.If question is repeated I am sorry, I could not find it

**EDIT**

Thank you all who help me get this done. Here is how I maintain the size of my application to meet the size of the screen it is being used on without going too big or too small and maintain the aspect ratio. 
Cheers

```
int width = frame.getBounds().width;
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
if (width > gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth())
    width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
while (width*4/5 > gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight())
    width = (int) (width - width*0.1);
frame.setBounds(frame.getBounds().x, frame.getBounds().y, width, width*4/5);
```

Comment: Frankly, it'd be easier and simpler to maintain the aspect ratio of the content, takes away any weirdness which might occur when the window is maximised by the system :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer but if I do that, the content inside the frame will look weird, also I am not sure if it is even possible because the sizes of all my components other than the frame has been set by the layout managers

Comment: So? Start by devising a layout manager which focuses on maintaining the ratio of a single container and then add the rest of your components into that container

Comment: @MadProgrammer, of course, :D The content pane, it is the ones that contain them all. Cheers :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have edited my question to show my final solution for the aspect ratio, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
    int W = 4;  
    int H = 3;  
    Rectangle b = arg0.getComponent().getBounds();
    arg0.getComponent().setBounds(b.x, b.y, b.width, b.width*H/W);
}
```

Comment: Overridden in what class? `JFrame` (and it's parent classes) don't implement this method

Comment: formComponentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt){}

Comment: Can we assume they aren't using some kind of form editor

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: ```addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
      ...
      }
    });```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **Resizeable** here

https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/drag/Resizeable.java

This works by taking the distance from 0,0 to width,height and then reallocating to x and y for the given aspect ratio (using sin and cos)